# Is there any way to create a separate machine and human CV?

Tags: resume

When creating a website its best practice that you consider both standard visitors (on a variety of devices) and also those visitors who are using screen-readers.

Something might be perfectly usable and pleasant for seeing visitors but to a blind person the entire thing is a unusable mess because the meta-data is fundamentally borked.

I've been thinking and I'm wondering whether I'm way off base here or are CVs and ATS systems somewhat similar?

I have a good CV made in illustrator and saved in PDF format which I've had for some years and have refined it to a very good place.  Unfortunately this CV doesn't work at all with ATS. Its almost funny how it completely fails to read what is amazingly obvious to human eyes.

I'm not massively concerned about this TBH- in these post covid days where the entire country is open to me and I'm senior enough and my field competitive enough that I can pick and choose where I work. If a company is relying on ATS for recruitment it says a lot about their values and quality as an organisation and is massive negative points towards whether I want to work there or not. In my field it is quite frowned upon to have a standard template CV of the sort 'career experts' always say to have; a key lesson I learned early in my career.

Nonetheless, this is a challenge that exists to be solved. How can I make a CV which is both original, attractive, and usable to human eyes; and works fine for robots?

Is there any way to embed completely separate meta-data in a PDF document that will attract the attention of the ATS whilst doing nothing to impact the experience of human readers?

Are there any 'hacks' that let one in a single file effectively upload two versions of a document for two different audiences?

Comment: I think this is more a software question than a Workplace question.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think it is a valid workplace question (but overly long) that boils down to "Can a resume be made to both be suitable for processing by computer, as well as formatted nicely for  people?".

Comment: Not sure if this is really an answer, because I haven't looked enough at this package to know if it is really what you want but maybe look at https://ctan.org/pkg/tagpdf

Comment: Unless you are interviewing for a graphic design position, nobody expects a fully typeset resume these days, and it may not even help you stand out from the crowd because the manager may only get the plaintext version. (And if you are a graphic designer, your portfolio is going to be more convincing than a pretty resume.)

Comment: It's a major issue with PDF. It's hard to make anything with PDF that works well with screen readers, just as it's hard to extract text from a PDF and have the words be in a correct order. As others say, not using PDF is the best solution, although I think Adobe have tried to improve in recent years so check you're up to date (Adobe now offer a text-to-speech tool which you should try). This is kind of off topic here though.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I make a CV which is both original, attractive, and usable to human eyes; and works fine for robots?

With Microsoft Word. Or StarOffice, or what-have-you.

People often care a lot about how their resumes look, because they only have the one and when they use it it's important to them that it make a good impression. So they end up stressing over margins and kerning. Generally this doesn't harm the resume too much, but I guess in your case it did.

Think about the last time you went through a set of applicants' resumes for a job. Did you care about *their* kerning and margins? Or did you just want to immediately find the information you care about, a task made easier by following a standard, boring structure and made no easier by how "refined" it is visually?

Your resume is never going to impress anyone. It should be straightforward and informative, attributes which are not significantly served by employing graphic design applications.

If an applicant submitted an "attractive" resume and a resume "for the computers", I'd throw away the former and read the latter.

Comment: To be clear here I'm not talking about submitting two separate CVs, thats obviously a bad idea, and rather more how to put an 'invisible' ATS CV in my real one.

For my part when recruiting- yes. I absolutely do care about the design of applicants CVs. I wouldn't instantly trash something using a default word template but if I see this, especially beyond a junior level, I will be instantly sceptical of the candidate; this is a mark upfront they're probably not suitable. Its starting them off on a negative front which if there's other decent candidates reduces their odds of interview.

Comment: @theotherone I won't press the issue; if nothing else, it's possible that you're in a field where graphic design skills are important, such that one's ability to draft an aesthetically pleasing resume would be a useful signal. But I would suggest that your focus on it may not be as widespread as you've assumed.

Comment: As for your question about metadata, though: While there are some dirty PostScript tricks through which one can include invisible blocks of text in a PDF (I remember reading an interesting digital signature exploit based on them), software which "scans" arbitrary PDFs does its best to exclude that sort of thing. I would expect the results to be unreliable at best.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a trick.

Flatten all your Illustrator work down to a simple PNG image.

Overlay this image with a text-only version of your resume. Make sure it's the same words. Put it on an invisible layer or in white color.

P.S. I assume you are working in graphics or otherwise design related field. Otherwise, there is no need for a resume that contains anything other than text.

Answer (score 0):

Just double up. I communicate in more than one language, often I'll have two versions in one document and a bookmark at the start so they can pick which to read.